# Authentication Error when connecting GCP with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to use GCP (Speech To Text service) in my spring boot application. However, I get the error:

```
  public String recognizeVoice(String encodedfile) throws IOException
     {
            System.out.println("encoded file inside recognize Voice  "+ encodedfile);
            SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(); // this line throws error
         System.out.println("client created succesflly" );
             // The path to the audio file to transcribe
             String gcsUri = "src/main/resources/samplesSounds/punjabiAudioSpeech.wav";

             // Builds the sync recognize request
             RecognitionConfig config =
                     RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                                      .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                                      .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                                      .setLanguageCode("pa-Guru-IN")
                                      .setModel("command_and_search")
                                      .setAudioChannelCount(2)
                                      .build();

             RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

             // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
             RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
             List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

             for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                 // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
                 // first (most likely) one here.
                 SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                 System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
             }
         return "FAILED";
     }
```

```
 Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:127) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.22.0.jar:1.22.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:152) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.22.0.jar:1.22.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:124) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.22.0.jar:1.22.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:70) ~[gax-2.42.0.jar:2.42.
```

I have tried setting up as a property in "application.properties " in spring boot. However, I am still getting this error. Property which I have set is:
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=key.json

They key.json file is generated through the service account in GCP. Is there anyother way I can access the services in cloud?

Comment: If you are using the key generated for a service account, try setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the file. 

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#wlif-key

Comment: Where do (will) you run your code? On your local workstation? On Google Cloud? Other platform?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am currently running it in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you do not need a service account key file. And it's a good news because this file is a security hole (you have a secret file that need to be handled like a secret)

On your local environment, you can use

- `gcloud auth application-default login` to use your own credentials (and roles)
- `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<sa-email>` to impersonate your service account and act as it (with its own roles. Useful to validate that the right roles are set)